# Высота ListView по содержимому

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть 2 listView. Причем один внутри другого. Как это глупо выглядит/звучит я понимаю. Нужно сделать чтобы 2-й ("внутренний") listView менял высоту по количеству ячеек (строк или пунктов). Например wrap_content не помогает - выводит всего один пункт списка.

Comment: Да, это плохая идея. Вам надо сделать 2 типа ячеек и отображать всё в одном ListView. А лучше - в RecyclerView. Если же очень хочется сделать неправильно (а при этом загрустит где-то один котёнок) то программно вычислите высоту всех ячеек внутреннего списка и задайте ему их сумму в качестве высоты.

Comment: Лучше опишите то, что хотите сделать/натворить, тут подскажут, как правильно это сделать.